# How can I auto increment variable value in php?

Tags: php, mysql

So I get records with mysql and ajax as something like this:

```
include 'config2.php';
$connection; 
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8 ");
$limit = 4; //how many items to show per page
$page = $_GET['page'];

if($page) 
    $start = ($page - 4) * $limit;          //first item to display on this page
else
    $start = 0;                             //if no page var is given, set start to 0
$limit++;
$query = "SELECT * FROM `adatok` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT $start, $limit " ; //You don't need a ; like you do in SQL
$result = mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
}
```

Working fine, but the problem is when you click the load more button again, where this code is runing, the increment is happend just once, and I would like to increment this number when the user click for the button, again, and again.
So how can I do this with automatically?
The ajax part:

```
function load(){
         $( ".video-body" ).fadeIn( "slow", function() {
       $.get( "next.php", function( data ) {
       'start': start,  
                            'limit': limit, 
  $( ".video-body" ).html( data );

    // Animation complete
  });
}); 
 }
```

Comment: Are you talking about `$limit`? It only lives for the duration of a single HTTP request. And I don't understand why you're incrementing it in the first place. I think this entire question betrays a fundamental misunderstanding of what HTTP, JavaScript and PHP _are_, and how programs written to use those technologies interact.

Comment: Yes I would like to increase `$limit` value.
I know the increment is run just once, that's becouse I looking for anwer for this problem.
I would like to load the post somthing simular like youtube load more.
And A very lot of google search fail and try over and over this seems like the simpleast soluttion for me.
Becouse If I have a variable, I can't change the value somehow.

Answer (score 1):

One simple way is to declare a global JS variable and pass it through the query string to `next.php` and increment it by `limit` upon success:

```
var start = <?php echo $start; ?>;
var limit = <?php echo $limit; ?>;
function load(){
    $( ".video-body" ).fadeIn( "slow", function() {
        $.get( "next.php?start=" + start + "&limit=" + limit, function( data ) {
            $( ".video-body" ).html( data );
            start = start + limit;
            // Animation complete
        });
    }); 
}
```

Then in your `next.php` file, you access the variable using `$_GET['start']` and `$_GET['limit']`.

Note how I've passed your PHP variables `$start` and `$limit` into your Javascript by using `<?php echo ... ; ?>` - this is because Javascript cannot see PHP variables without them being explicitly passed along. There are many assumptions with the above snippet, a main one being that the initial Javascript code is being loaded within the same PHP page that declares starting `$start` and `$limit` variables.

Comment: Unfortunetly I get the same record again and again.
You can test it in here:
http://neocsatblog.mblx.hu/addvideos/type.html

Comment: Oh i forget it ppress ctrl+i

Comment: @NewBieinPrograming Lol I don't even see my snippet in your source code. There's a lot of other messy Javascript in there, it's very hard to understand what's going on.

Comment: You can see your snipset when you press the big button.

Comment: Otherwise, yes we have a very lot of script and yes, if we're done, we do a veryy massive clean up.

Comment: Otherwise I can't add your code in fontpage becouse I get token erorr on console, but on next.php I dosn't get anything erorr expect for I get the same record always.

Comment: Actualy I get this:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;
For:
var start = ;
Somehow I no get record *.*